# How to properly link to pages?

Tags: html

I have a sidebar with basic link that should appear on every page:

- about
- engage
- contribute

If I go from main page and click on *about* link, how to go to *engage* from that page?

I have created multiple directories with .html files for every page. Right now I am using this method:

```
href="../../engage/engage.html"
```

but it gets complicated when making more pages and subdirectories.

Also, bonus question, is that a good way to organize webpages?

Thank you.

Comment: Look up "absolute URLs" and "relative URLs"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I believe your problem is only happening because of your directory structure. I wouldn't use it, as I prefer a more navigational and hierarchical structure.

This may turn out to be a big mess as structure grows, but when it does, you shouldn't be using simple HTML.

If you have a lot of duplicated code in different HTML pages, you may want to use something else, such as PHP, to load your pages.

For example, if you use PHP, you make your index.php page load the duplicated code everytime, like headers, footers, toolbars, and the content page based on a path parameter (e.g. /index.php?page=engage.html). The good thing is: when you load pages that way, using the `include('engage.html')`, all the links in the pages you load refer to the relative path from index.

Any links to your other pages would look like this: `href="index.php?page=about.html"`. With proper setup, it may even be cleaner: `yourwebsite.com/?p=somedir/page.html`.